# Lazy loading references from normalized Redux store

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, redux

Yo! I'm using Redux and [Normalizr](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr). The API I'm working with sends down objects that look like this:

```
{
  name: 'Foo',
  type: 'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP'
}
```

or like this

```
{
  name: 'Foo2',
  children: [
    'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP',
    'QRST-UVWX-YZAB-CDEF'
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to asynchronously fetch those related entities (`type` and `children`) when the above objects are accessed from the state (in `mapStateToProps`). Unfortunately, this does not seem to mesh with the Redux way as `mapStateToProps` is not the right place to call actions. Is there an obvious solution to this case that I'm overlooking (other than pre-fetching all of my data)?

Comment: sorry if it is obvious, but what do you mean by "accessed"?

Comment: @jamesemanon In this case by "accessed" I mean "denormalized". For instance, when the second object is fetched from the store in `mapStateToProps` it needs to be denormalized so that those IDs turn into usable objects (I'm currently trying to use https://github.com/gpbl/denormalizr for this). It's at that point that I'd like to dispatch an async action to fetch the object with ID `ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP` if it isn't already in the store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that I have correctly understood your use-case, but if you want to fetch data, one simple common way is to trigger it from a React component:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        if (!this.props.myObject) {
            dispatch(actions.loadObject(this.props.myObjectId));
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        const heading = this.props.myObject ?
            'My object name is ' + this.props.myObject.name
            : 'No object loaded';
        return (
            <div>
                {heading}
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Given the "myObjectId" prop, the component triggers the "myObject" fetching after mounting.

Another common way would be to fetch the data, if it's not already here, from a Redux async action creator (see [Redux's doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) for more details about this pattern):

```
// sync action creator:
const FETCH_OBJECT_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_OBJECT_SUCCESS';
function fetchObjectSuccess(objectId, myObject) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_OBJECT_SUCCESS,
        objectId,
        myObject,
    };
}

// async action creator:
function fetchObject(objectId) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const currentAppState = getState();
        if (!currentAppState.allObjects[objectId]) {
            // fetches the object if not already present in app state:
            return fetch('some_url_.../' + objectId)
                .then(myObject => (
                    dispatch(fetchObjectSuccess(objectId, myObject))
                ));
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve();  // nothing to wait for
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @ntdb do these standard ways of fetching data in a react/redux app solve your problem?